# Use AWK to safely search and replace URLs in Wordpress SQL-Dump

Tags: wordpress, search, awk, replace, command-line

I am working on a webtool to mirror a Wordpress installation into a development system.

The aim is to have a Live system for production and a development system for testing. The webtool then offers a one-click-sync between those systems.
Each of the systems is standalone, with its own webroot, database and url.

I am having a trouble with the database dump in which I have to search all the references to the source and replace them with the URL of the destination (e.g.: "www.example.com" -> "www-dev.example.com").

What I need to do is:

1. Find all occurences of the URL and replace it with the new one.
2. IF the match also matches the format of a serialized string it should set the Field-Seperator, and reload the match, so that the actual length can be set in the array.

In a first attempt I tried to solve this with a 'sed' command looking as follows: `sed -i.orig 's/360\.example\.com/360-dev\.my\.example\.dev/g'`.
This didn't work because there are serialized arrays contained in the dump, containing the url. The `sed` command is no good for updating the string-length-indicator of the serialized arrays.

My latest attempt is to use an `awk` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902647/sed-match-replace-url-and-update-serialized-array-count), because it's capable of arithmetic operations.

My `awk` script looks like this:

```
/360[.]example[.]com/ {
    sub("360.example.com", "360-dev.my.example.dev");
    if ($0 ~ /s:[[:digit:]]+:["](http[s]?:\/\/)?360[.]example[.]com["]/){
        FS="\"";
        $0=$0;
        n=length($2)-1;
        sub(/:[[:digit:]]+:/, ":" n ":");
    }
} 1
```

There seem to be some errors in my script, which I can't find. It does not replace all of the occurrences of the url and completely skips the length-indicator-update.

How can I fix my script to achieve what I want to do?

EDIT: (Added Input/Output samples)
Databasedump consists of the whole wordpress-database with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` and `INSERT` statements for each table and record.

Normal (unserialized) occurence:

```
(36, 'home', 'http://360.example.com/blogname', 'yes'),
```

should result in:

```
(36, 'home', 'http://360-dev.my.example.dev/blogname', 'yes'),
```

Serialized occurence:

```
(404, 'wp-maintenance-mode', 'a:21:{s:6:"active";i:1;s:4:"time";i:0;s:4:"link";i:1;s:7:"support";i:0;s:10:"admin_link";i:1;s:7:"rewrite";s:0:"";s:6:"notice";i:1;s:4:"unit";i:1;s:5:"theme";i:0;s:8:"styleurl";s:69:"http://360.example.com/wp-content/themes/blogname/css/maintenance.css";s:5:"index";i:0;s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:6:"header";s:0:"";s:7:"heading";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:12:"Example Text";s:7:"exclude";a:1:{i:0;s:0:"";}s:6:"bypass";i:0;s:4:"role";a:1:{i:0;s:13:"administrator";}s:13:"role_frontend";a:1:{i:0;s:13:"administrator";}s:5:"radio";i:0;s:4:"date";s:0:"";}', 'yes'),
```

Should result in:

```
(404, 'wp-maintenance-mode', 'a:21:{s:6:"active";i:1;s:4:"time";i:0;s:4:"link";i:1;s:7:"support";i:0;s:10:"admin_link";i:1;s:7:"rewrite";s:0:"";s:6:"notice";i:1;s:4:"unit";i:1;s:5:"theme";i:0;s:8:"styleurl";s:76:"http://360-dev.my.example.dev/wp-content/themes/blogname/css/maintenance.css";s:5:"index";i:0;s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:6:"header";s:0:"";s:7:"heading";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:12:"Example Text";s:7:"exclude";a:1:{i:0;s:0:"";}s:6:"bypass";i:0;s:4:"role";a:1:{i:0;s:13:"administrator";}s:13:"role_frontend";a:1:{i:0;s:13:"administrator";}s:5:"radio";i:0;s:4:"date";s:0:"";}', 'yes'),
```

EDIT 2:
Now using `wp-cli` to do the task of search & replace.
I've got a multisite setup with blogs numbered (2,3,9). 
Executing `wp search-replace --url=360.example.com '360.example.com' '360-dev.my.example.dev'` results in an error, telling me that the Single-Site tables (wp_redirection_items and wp_redirection_groups) cannot be found.
This is true, because they really do not exist, but rather for each blog (e.g: wp_2_redirection_items and so on). This error results in over 9000 missed occurences in s&r. It's possible to replace everything with `wp search-replace --url=360.example.com '360.example.com' '360-dev.my.example.com' wp_*`. But it still throws the error.

Comment: Can you use [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/)? it can easily do that: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/

Comment: actually i am already using wp-cli, but did oversee that command... Sorry to bother you! I'll try it out and keep you updated if it suffits my need! :)

Comment: The command is already helping a lot. But it throws an error, and tells me it can't find table "wp_redirection_items" for an INNER JOIN on "wp_redirection_groups". I have got a multisite setup here, so these tables do in fact not exist, but "wp_2_redirection_items" and so on... Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @archimiro the task now is done by [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/).
But as I am also having a multisite setup, which lead to some errors I had to figure out the command for a full database search-replace task.

The final command:
`wp search-replace --url=360.example.com '360.example.com' '360-dev.my.example.dev' wp_*`.
Without explicitly telling wp-cli to search&replace in ALL (`wp_*`) tables it would stop by the time a "table not found" error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Also not awk or wpcli but this is a php function I wrote that seems to work well.

```
    function snr($search, $replace, $inputfile, $outputfile){
    $sql = file_get_contents($inputfile);
    $sql1 = str_replace($search,$replace,$sql);
    file_put_contents($outputfile,$sql1);
    $serstrings = preg_split("/(?<=[{;])s:/",$sql1);

    foreach($serstrings as $i=>$serstring) {
        if (!!strpos($serstring, $replace)){
        $justString = str_replace("\\","",str_replace("\\\\","j",explode('\\";',explode(':\\"',$serstring)[1])[0]));
        $correct = strlen($justString);
        $serstrings[$i] = preg_replace('/^\d+/',$correct, $serstrings[$i]);
         } 
    }
    file_put_contents($outputfile,implode("s:",$serstrings));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've used this in past with success:

```
sed 's|360\.example\.com|360-dev\.my\.example\.dev|g' com.sql > local.sql
```

*Edit: sorry not awk, but neither is wp-cli.*